# Laravel 5 - static image assets broken when passing parameter in URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I pass a URL parameter (Laravel 5.4) I'm seeing the static images on my page not load (the usual broken place holder image instead) but without the URL parameter and using the exact same view, they load fine. So `http://localhost/site/public/filmpage` shows images but `http://localhost/site/filmpage/batman` doesn't show images (all other assets load fine). Wondering why this is, and how to fix it please?

I've got my web.php route file with:

```
Route::get('filmpage', 'FilmController@filmpagetest');
Route::get('filmpage/{name}', 'FilmController@filmpage');
```

then controller file with:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FilmController extends Controller
{
    public function filmpage($name)
        {
        return view('filmpage',array('name' => $name));
        }

    public function filmpagetest()
        {
        return view('filmpage',array('name' => 'hello'));
        }
}
```

I'm running Laravel on my Win 7 64 bit machine, PHP 5.6.24, Bitnami WAMP Stack 7.1.2.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: can you show us your view? It will be helpful to solve the question.

Comment: view is just a very simple plain HTML file in a blade template (layout.blade.php) with @yield('content') in the middle of it, then a separate blade template for the main page content. However, for both the working page and the non working one, it's using the same layout page.

Comment: Weird thing is when I view rendered page source in Chrome browser, for both the working and non working page, the HTML link to the broken image in both is: src="images/logo-small.png" BUT when I hover mouse over the link, the actual full image path shown (in the bottom of the view source window in Chrome) is /localhost/site/public/images/logo-small.png for the working page but for the non working one (with parameter) it's: /localhost/site/public/filmpage/images/logo-small.png - wrong path because of the 'filmpage' bit...

Comment: instead of `array('name'  => $name)` try `return view('filmpage')->with('name',$name);` and show it by `$name` . Hope it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Using informations you provided I think your assets are linked like that:

```
/path/to/asset/file.ext
```

but you are loading images using paths like that:

```
path/to/image.ext
```

Note missing `/` and the beginning.
Thats is why your images may not be loaded.

Comment: I tried putting a / in front of the paths in the route file Route::get('/filmpage', 'FilmController@filmpagetest');
Route::get('/filmpage/{name}', 'FilmController@filmpage'); but it made no difference...

Comment: please see reply to Adarsh above too

Comment: This is the way I solved the problem... src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/path/to/image.svg"